# outerHight doesn't take table hight

Tags: javascript, jquery, height

I use `var targetHeight = jQuery('.acc-content-inner').eq(currIndex).outerHeight();` to take hight of an element. But if the div.acc-content-inner has a table in it, it doesn't add the height from the tabele to the targetHeight

Comment: How & Where are you using this line of code?

Comment: seems fine here http://jsfiddle.net/z2eounmt/

Comment: I use it here http://dev.bffbern.ch/de/Fachliteratur/Medienkompetenz-als-Schluesselkompetenz

Answer (score 0):

The height may not be calculated right not because of the table, but because of the images. If you run your code on `document.ready`. My guess is that jQuery calculates it before the images get downloaded. A similar effect can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/z2eounmt/1/ (notice it disappears on page refreshing if cache is not cleared). The first time the output is `40`, so the height of the image is not included.

To solve this issue, either use [imagesLoaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded), or change your function to be run on `window.load.` or change the way your accordion works.